# php5-fpm cURL returns 200 but JSON data empty

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to make a REST call with cURL and the response is showing 200 while the JSON data is empty e.g., `{}`. When I try the same call with a REST client the response contains the correct data:

```
{
    "acceptLanguage": "en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-CA;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4,es;q=0.2,ar;q=0.2,de;q=0.2"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
$url = "http://my/api/service?_=1392236562419";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , True);
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);
```

Do I need to escape quotes or something, or is my cURL request missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you including the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` here for debugging purposes, or is it _in_ the code, and do you try to run a `json_decode()` on `json` _including_ headers? And that servers seems to return a specific `HTTP` header, does it perhaps return the value of the HTTP header _you_ send (which is empty in this case, as curl won't send a default `Accept-language` AFAIK)? And why are you sending a `Content-type` with no body? Do you mean to send a `Accept:` header?

Comment: I was including it for debugging. I did try to run `json_decode()` but it just outputs `NULL` with `var_dump()`: `$json = json_decode($response);
var_dump($json);`

Comment: Yes, I'd remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);`, and change `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Content-Type: application/json'));` to `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/json'));`, does anything happen then? If still not correct, what happens if you add that accept-language header?

Comment: `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/json'));` outputs: `object(stdClass)#1 (1)`, adding `'Accept-Language: en-US'` outputs: `object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["acceptLanguage"]=> string(5) "en-US" }`.

Comment: So, it indeed reflects back your header. If you add the `Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-CA;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4,es;q=0.2,ar;q=0.2,de;q=0.2` as per your working example instead, I'd say that would be reflected back, and I think we can safely say: "it works"?